# Recursive Shuffle Algo throws StackOverflow Error

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, shuffle

This is a recursive implementation of the Fisher-Yates shuffle. Why does this throw a StackOverflow error when I give it as little as 10000 items as input?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = algo3(10000);
}

public static int[] algo3(int n)
{
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++)
        a[i] = i;
    algo3(a, 0);
    return a;
}

public static void algo3(int[] a, int pos)
{
    if (pos == a.length - 1)
        return;
    int tmp = a[pos];
    int rand = randInt(pos,a.length); // line #27
    a[pos] = a[rand];
    a[rand] = tmp;
    algo3(a,pos + 1); // line #30
}

private static int randInt(int i, int j)
{
    return (int) (Math.random() * (j - i)) + i; // line #35
}
```

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong.compareAndSet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Random.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Random.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Math.random(Unknown Source)
    at nl.saxion.Week1.randInt(Week1.java:35)
    at nl.saxion.Week1.algo3(Week1.java:27)
    at nl.saxion.Week1.algo3(Week1.java:30)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fischer-Yates in a recursive system will do one level for each member in the array to shuffle.

Stack-overflow will happen long before 10,000 levels of calls.

Is there some special reason why you cannot use the while-loop version? It is much simpler, faster, and more reliable..... It's a 5-liner algorithm.... as a while-loop.

---

EDIT. As a test I wrote the following:

```
private static final void recurse(int val) {
    System.out.println(val);
    recurse(val + 1);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    recurse(1);
}
```

Care to guess where I got the overflow exception? Huh, **never**! I guess that my JIT compiled it out as a loop instead of recursion, and I killed the process somewhere past '1816130'.

Answer (score 1):

10000 is a big number especially because you are handling a 10 000 elements array. You can twick the size of the stack by using the `-Xss` JVM parameter.

Comment: Well, you *could* tweak the size of the stack, but all that really is going to do is raise the ceiling a little higher, rather than removing the ceiling entirely.